# Play: error: not found: value playScalaSettings

Tags: scala, build, playframework, sbt, ivy

I'm trying to create a new play application, myFirstApp, in Scala using sbt 0.12. I've build.sbt, in myFirstApp/ folder. I've also added plugins.sbt to myFirstApp/project/ folder.

**Build.sbt**

```
import play.Project._

name := "My first application"

version := "1.0"

playScalaSettings
```

**plugins.sbt**

```
// Typesafe snapshots
resolvers += "Typesafe Snapshots" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/snapshots/"

resolvers += "Typesafe Releases" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

// Use the Play sbt plugin for Play projects
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.2.0-M1")
```

**build.properties**

```
sbt.version=0.12.3
```

On executing sbt from myFirstApp folder, I get this **error**:

```
error: not found: value playScalaSettings
```

How do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just change

**build.properties**

```
sbt.version=0.13.0
```

and

**plugins.sbt**

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.2.3")
```

As of May 9th, 2014, last stable version for the plugin is 2.2.3. You can check [Typesafe repo](http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.play/sbt-plugin/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/) for current releases.

There is currently no SBT 0.12.x plugin for Play 2.2: http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/com.typesafe.play/sbt-plugin/scala_2.10/
and I M1 is also not in the repo http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/com.typesafe.play/sbt-plugin/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/